# Yii: Dependant dropdownlist fill 7 text box

Tags: list, yii, textbox

i have form with one dropdown list, below of it there is 7 text box to be filled when select a list from dropdown list.

i'm still not get on it when learn from this:  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/creating-a-dependent-dropdown/

please help me.

thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Im searching all around without solution, not even a simple example.

Comment: what are you using yii or yii2?

Comment: Im using yii. (I have see before in yii2, but i dont really need it yet right now.

Answer (score 0):

**[Try This](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/429/an-easy-solution-for-dependent-dropdownlist-using-ajax/)**

**Code In VIEW**:

```
<?php                                   
  echo CHtml::dropDownList('region_id','', 
  array(2=>'New England',1=>'Middle Atlantic',3=>'East North Central'),

  array(
    'prompt'=>'Select Region',
    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST', 
    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('YourController/loadcities'),
    'update'=>'#city_name', //or 'success' => 'function(data){...handle the data in the     way you want...}',
  'data'=>array('region_id'=>'js:this.value'),
  ))); 

    echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_name','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));
?>
```

**And In CONTROLLER**

```
public function actionLoadcities()
{
   $data=RegionCity::model()->findAll('region_id=:region_id', 
   array(':region_id'=>(int) $_POST['region_id']));

   $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','city_name');

   echo "<option value=''>Select City</option>";
   foreach($data as $value=>$city_name)
   echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($city_name),true);
}
```

Comment: Im still bump into nothing, the second dropdown list show nothing.   :-(